# Why does syncrepl do nothing when ldapsearch works fine?

Tags: ldap, openldap, rhel7

I'm trying to set up LDAP multi-master replication using OpenLDAP on Red Hat 7 (with very little preexisting knowledge of LDAP).

As a first stage, I've got syncprov installed:

```
# ldif format
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: syncprov.la
```

and enabled:

```
# ldif format
dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncprov
olcSpSessionLog: 100
```

And I've tried to create syncrepl entries using simple binding as the sync method, like this (I figure I can switch to TLS later):

```
# ldif format
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcServerID
olcServerID: 1

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcSyncRepl

olcSyncRepl: rid=134 provider=ldap://ws2/  bindmethod=simple searchbase="dc=tcs,dc=local" type=refreshAndPersist interval=00:00:00:10 retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1

add: olcMirrorMode
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
```

("ws1" and "ws2" are two servers on an isolated local LAN.)

I know it's *possible* for the servers to reach each other since I can use ldapsearch to connect to either of them from the other, e.g.:

```
admin@ws1$ ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ws2/ -LLL "(objectClass=posixAccount)" dn
dn: uid=testuser1,ou=People,dc=tcs,dc=local
# ...
```

But they never actually seem to sync their data and I can find no indication why.

How do I troubleshoot syncrepl functionality if I've already established that basic LDAP communication is working, but no replication occurs?